# Can a student id card can be taken as an identity proof for domestic air travel in India?

Tags: air-travel, india

I have a student id card verified by my institution. My father works in defence so I also have a family identity card with a photograph attached to it. I would like to know if I will be allowed to enter the airport and travel from Lucknow to Hyderabad?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can use your student ID card issued by your university to take the domestic flights in India.

The Bureau of Civil Aviation Security (BCAS) has issued a list of documents accepted at the airport. The list could be found here:

https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/10-documents-you-can-use-at-airports-to-prove-identity/articleshow/61281345.cms